# Android Jwplayer: issue illegalstatexception

Tags: android, jwplayer

I am using jwplayer with audio content. I am playing audio in between press home button then getting issue Java.lang.illegalstateexception

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Stop failed.
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaCodec.native_stop(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaCodec.stop(MediaCodec.java:2072)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.releaseCodec(SourceFile:469)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.onDisabled(SourceFile:434)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.onDisabled(SourceFile:289)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.TrackRenderer.disable(SourceFile:231)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.ensureDisabled(SourceFile:661)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopAndDisable(SourceFile:562)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(SourceFile:551)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(SourceFile:528)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(SourceFile:247)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(SourceFile:40)

Comment: Call Jwplayer.onPause() in onPause() method